# triggering a requestanimation reactjs hook in a button click

Tags: reactjs

I have this hook which is to abstract `requestAnimationFrame`:

```
export const useAnimationIncrease = ({
  easingName = EasingName.linear,
  diff: end,
  duration = 500
}: AnimationIncreaseProps) => {
  const [increase, setIncrease] = useState(0);
  const start = useRef<any>(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let raf: number;

    const frame = (timestamp: number) => {
      if (!start.current) {
        start.current = timestamp;
      }

      const time = timestamp - start.current;

      // get percent of completion in range [0, 1]
      const percentRange = Math.min(time / duration, 1);

      const percent = easing[easingName as string](percentRange);

      setIncrease(increase + end * percent);

      if (time < duration) {
        raf = requestAnimationFrame(frame);
      }
    };

    raf = requestAnimationFrame(frame);

    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
    };
  },              [end]);

  return increase;
};
```

it used like this:

```
const increase = useAnimationIncrease({ easingName: EasingName.inOutCubic, diff: 10 });
```

It will return the increase each time so I can use it for scrolling etc.

How would I trigger this in a button click though or am I approaching this wrong.

If I try this;

```
onClick={(e) => {
  const increase = useAnimationIncrease({ easingName: EasingName.inOutCubic, diff: 10 });
  // use increase
}
```

Then I get the error message:

> Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

Comment: Is the `onClick` handler inside a class component? And what are your `react` and `react-dom` versions?

Comment: Could you attach codesandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the rules of hooks

> **Only Call Hooks at the Top Level**
>
> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.
>   Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By
>   following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same
>   order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to
>   correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and
>   useEffect calls. (If you’re curious, we’ll explain this in depth
>   below.)

And since you are violating that rule by calling hooks in `onClick` event handler, you are getting this warning

As a workaround you can set a variable which you can use to trigger the animation

```
export const useAnimationIncrease = ({
  easingName = EasingName.linear,
  diff: end,
  duration = 500
}: AnimationIncreaseProps) => {
  const [increase, setIncrease] = useState(0);
  const [startAnimation, setStartAnimation] = useState(0);
  const start = useRef<any>(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let raf: number;

    const frame = (timestamp: number) => {
      if (!start.current) {
        start.current = timestamp;
      }

      const time = timestamp - start.current;

      // get percent of completion in range [0, 1]
      const percentRange = Math.min(time / duration, 1);

      const percent = easing[easingName as string](percentRange);

      setIncrease(increase + end * percent);

      if (time < duration) {
        raf = requestAnimationFrame(frame);
      }
    };

    raf = requestAnimationFrame(frame);

    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
    };
  },[end, startAnimation]);

  return [increase, startAnimation, setStartAnimation];
};
```

and use it like

```
const [increase, startAnimation, setStartAnimation] = useAnimationIncrease({ easingName: EasingName.inOutCubic, diff: 10 });

onClick={(e) => {
   setStartAnimation(prev => prev + 1);
   // use increase now
}
```